# Syntax for adding to this T-SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I built a simple UI for our users to query on our SQL Server DB.  The UI started off as just one input field for a person's name.  This field's input would be used to search on 3 fields on our database.  The query up until now looks like this:

```
SELECT [Id], [Url], [PersonName], [BusinessName], [DOB], [POB], [Text]
FROM dbo.DataAggregate 
WHERE CONTAINS([PersonName], 'NEAR((john, doe), 2, FALSE)') 
OR CONTAINS([BusinessName], 'NEAR((john, doe), 2, FALSE)')
OR CONTAINS([Text], 'NEAR((john, doe), 2, FALSE)')
```

The above assumes the user queried on John Doe.  The requirement for NEAR has to do with the format inconsistencies across data in our fields, but that's not relevant to this question, just an FYI.

Now, I've been instructed to add 4 more input fields in the UI to allow users to further tailor their query.  These fields already exist in the DB records. My question is how do I add on to the above query for when the additional fields in the UI are used?  Am I simply just adding several AND statements to it or OR statements to it?

Let me give an example to help you help me:

```
User Query:
Person Name: John Doe
DOB:         01/01/1900
Address:     123 Main St
POB:         USA
Occupation:  Worker
```

How would I add to my query to include the data for the other 4 input fields?  Initially, to handle which input fields are populated and which are not, do I need IF statements in the query?

Each value in the other 4 input fields would need to be searched for in its own field, plus the Text field - i.e.
-The DOB would need to searched for in the DOB field and Text field
-The Address would need to searched for in the Address field and the Text field
etc.

It just seems there has to be a more efficient way to structure a query like this than having basically 5 sections similar to my above query separated by IF/AND/OR.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you use parameters you can get round unpopulated inputs with this trick

```
Where 
((@input1 is null) or (somefield = @input1))
Or / And
...
```

This is going to get messy real quick though, they'll come up with more inputs next week.

Other options

```
Grid with Filter capability.
Data dump for say Excel 
Building the query programatically, with parameters.
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice thus far - for now let's assume no more inputs will be thrown at me.  I will certainly explore those other options you mentioned as well.

Comment: You also have to consider which (if any) inputs are mandatory, and which are optional. If you MUST enter a name, then your other inputs will be handled differently.  Since it is the hardest case, I assume that all of your inputs will be optional. Also, will the other fields also be checked in three different locations?

Comment: @LaughingVergil while it's not technically mandatory, the user will always at least enter something in the name field. The other 4 will always be optional.  As to your last question, the other 4 input fields will be checked in two different locations - their own field, and the Text field.